# What is the largest value sizeof(T) can yield?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, sizeof, size-t

At first one might think `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, but if there was an object that huge, could it still offer a one-past-the-end pointer? I guess not. Does that imply the largest value `sizeof(T)` could yield is `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()-1`? Am I right, or am I missing something?

Comment: Does an object *need* to offer a one-past-the-end pointer?

Comment: @Dabbler: According to the C++ standard, yes, because as far as pointer arithmetic is concerned, an object can be treated as an array of size 1. I can look up the exact wording if you want.

Comment: @Mike: Wrong, 5.7 §1 says `For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the
first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.`

Comment: I'm not seeing the correlation between an object `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` large, and the inability of the system to provide a one-past-the-end pointer.

Comment: @Dennis: ...because size_t and intptr_t are _different_ things

Comment: I know of no implementation where `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(char*)` and simultaneously allows you to instantiate an object of size `(size_t)-1`. As such the question "how does the implementation satisfy the requirements of the standard in such a case" is moot, as such case will never arise. The question "what is the largest value of `sizeof(T)`" is very much implementation-defined, but it certainly can be `(size_t)-1` if `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(char*)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: What is the largest value sizeof(T) can yield?

A: `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`

Clearly, sizeof cannot return a value larger than `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, since it wouldn't fit.  The only question is, can it return `...::max()`?

Yes. Here is a valid program, that violates no constraints of the C++03 standard, which demonstrates a proof-by-example. In particular, this program does not violate any constraint listed in §5.3.3 [expr.sizeof], nor in §8.3.4 [dcl.array]:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
 typedef char T[std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()];
 std::cout << sizeof(T)<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you actually read the question in full? Fred discusses why he thinks that might be wrong. How can you come >10mins after the question and provide an answer contradicting his doubts without even arguing them?

Comment: +1, although the question remains what value the one-past-the-end pointer will have.

Comment: Hm, that prints `4294967295` on my computer, so I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @sbi: To be fair, Rob proved me wrong with a counter example.

Comment: There's a great deal turning on the difference between "largest value `sizeof(T)` can return" and "largest variable that can actually be instantiated" here (even ignoring the actual memory capacity of any given computer) ;-)

Comment: @sbi: That's always a possibility one has to take into account, of course :)

Comment: Just because your implementation can doesn't make it Standard. Visual C++ can take the address of rvalues and a bunch of other dodgy things, but they're not Standard either.

Comment: @sbi -- sorry, I thought my argument was clear. Let me rephrase: Here is a valid program, that violates no constraints of the C++03 standard, which demonstrates a proof-by-example. In particular, this program does not violate any constraint listed in §5.3.3 [expr.sizeof], nor in §8.3.4 [dcl.array].

Comment: @Rob: I needed to edit anyway in order to undo my voting, so I put that statement into your answer. I hope you don't mind, but feel free to remove it if you do. I didn't upvote, because I'm not convinced either way yet, but with this explanation at least my downvote seemed unjustified.

Answer (score 3):

If `std::numeric_limits<ptrdiff_t>::max() > std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` you can compute the size of an object of size `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` by subtracting a pointer to it from a one-past-the-end pointer.

If `sizeof(T*) > sizeof(size_t)` you can have enough distinct pointers to address each and every single byte inside that object (in case you have an array of char, for example) plus one for one-past-the-end.

So, it's possible to write an implementation where `sizeof` can return `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, and where you can get pointer to one-past-the-end of an object that large.

Comment: If the implementation targets a platform with segmented addresses, `sizeof(T*) > sizeof(size_t)` could easily be true.

Comment: "I doubt there is one such implementation [where `sizeof` can return `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`]". g++ is one such implementation.

Answer (score 2):

it's not exactly well-defined. but to stay within safe limits of the standard, max object size is `std::numeric_limits<ptrdiff_t>::max()`

that's because when you subtract two pointers, you get a `ptrdiff_t`

which is a signed integer type

cheers & hth.,

Comment: Sadly, you can have an array larger than `std::numeric_limits<ptrdiff_t>::max()`. If you subtract two pointers within this array that are too far apart, the behavior is undefined, see [expr.add]/6.

Comment: @avakar: I'll be damned! Nice find. `As with any other arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided, the behavior is undefined.`

Answer (score 1):

The requirement to be able to point beyond the end of an array has nothing to do with the range of `size_t`. Given an object `x`, it's quite possible for `(&x)+1` to be a valid pointer, even if the number of bytes separating the two pointers can't be represented by `size_t`.

You could argue that the requirement *does* imply an upper bound on object size of the maximum range of pointers, minus the alignment of the object. However, I don't believe the standard says anywhere that such a type can't be defined; it would just be impossible to instantiate one and still remain conformant.

Answer (score 0):

If this was a test, I'd say `(size_t) -1`

Comment: That's `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Answer (score 0):

A `sizeof()` expression yields a value of type `size_t`. From C99 standard 6.5.3.4:

> The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an
>   unsigned integer type) is size_t, defined in stddef.h (and other
>   headers).

Therefore, the maximum value that sizeof() can yield is SIZE_MAX.

Comment: That's the maximum value that can be stored in a `size_t`. It doesn't mean `sizeof` uses all the values of `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a standard compliant compiler that allows for object sizes that cause pointer arithmetic to overflow; however, the result is undefined. From the C++ standard, 5.7 [expr.add]:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted,
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed
>   integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as
>   `std::ptrdiff_t` in the `<cstddef>` header (18.2). As with any other
>   arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided,
>   the behavior is undefined.